# Converting Apache rewrite rules to an nginx config file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a pretty simple `.htaccess` file which I need to convert over to an nginx config:

```
RewriteRule ^api$ api.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I tried to make a start by doing:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;
}
```

but whenever I load the base URL of my web page my browser just downloads the index.php file. I do also have this in my config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

but for some reason nginx still passes it as a download. What's the correct config here?

Comment: This isn't an htaccess, apache, or rewrite issue. This is an nginx/fastcgi configuration issue.

Comment: The fastcgi rules work with everything else. I have other scripts running on the server with the same config and they work fine, I think it's just the rewrite rule stopping it from running and instead downloading the file to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

the first 3 you'd do with a try_files not a rewrite in nginx (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files for details on that directive):

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php$args;
}

location = /api {
  rewrite ^ /api.php$args
}
```